# Яндекс карты. Как изменить размер меток при смене разрешения?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Собственно, суть вопроса в заголовке. Как можно изменить размер метки iconImageSize: [x, y] при смене разрешения экрана. Т.е. например, на десктопе метка должна быть 30х50, а на планшете и ниже 20x35

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете определять устройство, например, с помощью `navigator.userAgent` или dpr устройства `window.devicePixelRatio`. 
Затем, в зависимости от типа устройства, выставлять нужные размеры метки.